# Github Pages Password Protected Website for Teaching?

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages, documentation

## Summary

I want a password protected repository that compiles as a website for documentation, orientation, and teaching for a team of student interns. The ideal scenario is an Enterprise Account with Github, which allows for this but is very expensive. Alternatives?

## Context

As a professor, I work with students and interns all the time on a variety of research-related projects, often using our unique and detailed datasets at our research institute. I want to do a better job of documenting our new processes and procedures, both internal use, "customer service", and orienting new interns. I also want a specific part of the documentation which is explicitely for orienting interns. A documentation-style website makes perfect sense and I want students to develop Git skills, too.

## Here are my criteria for this documentation approach.

- documentation must be version controlled in some way
- multiple users should be able to contribute independently
- documentation needs to be protected so it's not entirely public
- underlying files should be in non-proprietary format (i.e. plain text, not Word or Google Docs)
- needs to be able to grow quickly and easily
- does not need fancy functionality; a static site is ideal

## Here's what doesn't work and why (plus some ideas):

- Google Docs: proprietary, messy file management
- AirTable: not really for writing
- Github Pages on free version: fully public
- Github Pages on Enterprise: allows private repos and password protected sites, but expensive per user
- Github repo website through Netlify: same $$$ per user costs are high
- Github repo with Markdown files that sync but NO website version: might work?, a little messy for navigation I think
- Notion: probably not terrible (free educational version is decent): proprietary!
- Craft: same as Notion, but more expensive; proprietary
- Wikipedia-style website hosted on a private or password protected server: could work?, might be too technical, not plain text files
- Obsidian vault shared with others: I've heard this is not a good solution, not designed for this
- most online "Write the Docs" services are pay-per-seat and, again, proprietary formats
- Jekyll- or Hugo-built website with password protection? I'm familiar with a Jekyll workflow that starts with Github repo, but the question is about password protection. Maybe there's another way to do this that isn't on Github, but another service that would accomplish the same thing?
- Perhaps GitLab has a cheaper or free functionality on Gitlab Pages? I'm not familiar with them.

That's where I'm at. Does anyone have a suggestion about an open source solution to this? It would such a huge service to my students and me.

Comment: Have you looked into [Wiki.js](https://js.wiki/)? It is a wiki, not as fully featured as wikipedia, but I think would meet your needs. Underlying files are html, txt, or md depending on what editor you use. It can also be synced with a git repo for backup storage and version control.  It can be hosted on a service such as digital ocean for relatively cheap depending on how many users.

Comment: I hadn't heard of this before, thank you! It does look like an excellent solution and I'm going to try it out this weekend.